# What causes this behaviour in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, safari

**Try the Pen with Chrome and Safari to see the issue first hand.**

Here is the pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmYJaJ#anon-login

As you scroll down the page, the navbar should hide and then if you scroll up, it should appear. It works as expected in Chrome

Chrome: 
[image: Chrome]

Safari:
[image]

The JS I'm using is

```
var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
var headerHeight = $('.navbar-default').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrolled > scroll) {
        $('.navbar-default').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('nav-up');
    } 
    if (scrolled > headerHeight) {
            $('.navbar-default').addClass('nav-white');
        } else {
            $('.navbar-default').removeClass('nav-white');
        }

    scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
});
```

How do I fix this and why does it happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are discrepancies with safari and other browsers when it comes to jQuery window height.

Changing your JS to:

```
var scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
var headerHeight = $('.navbar-default').outerHeight();
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (scrolled > scroll) {
    $('.navbar-default').addClass('nav-up');
  } else {
    $('.navbar-default').removeClass('nav-up');
  } 
  if (scrolled > headerHeight) {
    $('.navbar-default').addClass('nav-white');
  } else {
        $('.navbar-default').removeClass('nav-white');
  }

  scroll = $(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).height();
});
```

The only thing changed here is this line, calculating offset to accommodate window.innerHeight, that is:

```
scroll = $(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $(document).height();
```

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pPpBrb